# "Ярлыки" в Gnome 3

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, gnome

Вопрос следующий - где Gnome 3 хранит .desktop-файлы для своего меню? Есть несколько сторонних приложений, которые лежат в виде готовых бинарников, мне бы в меню их засунуть бы неплохо бы. Заодно буду благодарен за ссылочку по структуре .desktop-файла.

Comment: можно поискать стандартные приложения find -name appl.desktop и осторожно поместить в папки(у) свое приложение. После наверное нужно перезайти в гном.

Comment: 1. *Заодно буду благодарен за ссылочку по структуре .desktop-файла* — всё описано в [спецификациях xdg](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/). 2. естественно, всё это никоим образом не-gnome, не-3 и вообще не-desktop-environment -специфично.

Comment: ну можно же у себя найти и открыть. там всего строк 10-15.

Comment: а простое перетаскивание в\на меню не работает?

Comment: Простое перетаскивание в Gnome 3 не работает, по крайней мере у меня.

Comment: странно. я раньше где-то читал что в гноме (наверное в его версиях, ориентированных на мобилустройства) даже хотят\хотели убрать контекстное меню. Ну шототипа потому что его нельзя использовать в мобильных устройствах.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно мучился аналогичной проблемой. Если отбросить всё, что связано с ENV переменными, то места только два:

1. /usr/share/applications - для общесистемного меню
2. ~/.local/share/application  - для меню конкретного пользователя

Локальные элементы имеют приоритет перед общесистемными. В ENV переменных можно установить значения, которые изменят эти настройки, но я такого не видел.

Answer (score 0):

Поищите стандартные приложения

```
find -name standartappl.desktop
```

и  поместить в папку, в которой будет расположен `standartappl.desktop`, свое приложение. После этого наверное нужно перезайти в гном.

У меня Кеды.

У меня контра тут.

```
xuser@mbs:~$ find -name Counter*.desktop
./.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Counter-Strike 1.6/Counter-Strike 1.6.desktop
./Рабочий стол/Links/Counter-Strike 1.6.desktop
xuser@mbs:~$
```

uGet где-то тут:

```
./.local/share/applications/uget-gtk-2.desktop
./.kde/share/icons/Numix-White/48/apps/uget-icon.svg
 ...
```

Так же само можно найти стандартные убу-приложения и в ту же папку поместить ваше.

***Но я на  100% не уверен на счет Гнома.***

ссылка на описание структуры: http://life-warrior.org/programs/gui-deb/manual/desktopfiles.html

Comment: почему-то он мне находит только "сторонние" вещи типа расширений хрома. а там внутри каша из имён и параметров

Comment: ??? это  вопрос. Вы искали из консоли? `find -name *.desktop` Хоть какие нибудь *.desktop файлы находит?